# Simple product calculation in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a simple product calculation function for mySQL. I have a column IQ in my_table which contains float values all walues are positive so it is not necessory to manage negative values. I need to calculate product for this column. Suggest me something please.

Comment: I suggest you to add sample data and expected output. What have you tried so far is also welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the product you can use the sum of logs with exponentiation:

```
select exp(sum(ln(x))
from t;
```

Note:  Depending on your range of values, floating point imprecision could affect the final result.